# use JS in Odoo inheriting from website.assets_frontend

Tags: javascript, odoo

I am trying to use my own Javascript in an odoo module, something to test, but I get a template error.
This is my views/template.xml

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_frontend" name="library_website_assets" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/upobeer/static/src/js/functions.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

And my static/src/js/functions.js

```
odoo.define('upobeer.library_website_assets', function (require) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('JS is work');
});
```

however, when installing the module I get this error

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing None:4, somewhere inside
<data name="library_website_assets" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/upobeer/static/src/js/functions.js"/>
            </xpath>
        </data>
```

I have views/templates.xml added in manifest.py

Comment: Can u try removing the `data` tag and also included the full error?

Answer (score 0):

the correct views/template.xml is

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_frontend" name="library_website_assets" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/upobeer/static/src/js/functions.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: I think you copied the incorrect file. This the same file as in your question.